# Unix - Waitpid 'status'

Tags: c, unix, signals, status, waitpid

I'm working on an Unix-Shell, using C langage.
I use waitpid to wait my processes to terminate and i want to know if my son process (created with `fork()` ) received a signal like `SIGSEGV`.

Current  code :

```
static const t_error    error[ERROR_NBR]= {
  {SIGHUP, "Hangup"},
  {SIGQUIT, "Quit (core dumped)"},
  {SIGABRT, "Abort (core dumped)"},
  {SIGBUS, "Bus error (core dumped)"},
  {SIGFPE, "Floating exception (core dumped)"},
  {SIGKILL, "Killed"},
  {SIGUSR1, "User signal 1"},
  {SIGSEGV, "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"},
  {SIGUSR2, "User signal 2"},
  {SIGPIPE, "Broken pipe"},
  {SIGTERM, "Terminated"},
};

void print_signal_message(int status)
{
 int i;
 if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
    status = WTERMSIG(status);
 else
    return ;
 i = -1;
 while (++i < ERROR_NBR)
   {
     if (status == error[i].error_status)
       {
         fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error[i].error);
         return ;
       }
   }
 return ;
}
int             xwaitpid(int pid, int *status, int opt)
{
  int           ret;

  ret = waitpid(pid, status, opt);
  if (ret == -1)
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't perfom waitpid (pid = %d)\n", pid);
  if (WIFEXITED(*status))
    *status = WEXITSTATUS(*status);
  else
    **print_sigerr(*status);**
  return (ret == -1 ? (1) : ret);
}
```

`xwaitpid` is called in the parent process.

It seems that WIFSIGNALED always returns TRUE, even when i execute a command like `false || true`.

Someone has a good idea that could help me ?

-> found my answer, thanks.

Comment: What's the apparent signal that is raised? Are you sure your code that starts the child is ok? (BTW, your code looks like it has a global variable `i`. If that's the case, erm..., don't do that.)

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `waitpid` correctly too? I can't see any call to it in the code you've shown, but it wouldn't surprise me if the status you pass in is 'wrong' some how.

Comment: @Mat : just forgot to put `int i`. The childs just calls `execve()`.

Comment: You show `print_signal_message()` but call `print_sigerr()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (WIFEXITED(*status))
    *status = WEXITSTATUS(*status);
```

That's your problem. You can't `WIFSIGNALED` on `*status` after that, you've lost the required bits in that `int`.

Comment: +1 for spotting the problem.  The status is a 16-bit value, with the exit value in the high order 8 bits and the signal information in the low order 8 bits.  When you extract the exit status with WEXITSTATUS and assign it to the same variable, you are effectively transferring the exit status information to where the signal information is stored, so (as diagnosed) it appears that everything was signalled.